# What is the official pod for G+ iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-plus, cocoapods, google-plus-signin

I need to integrate [Google+ iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) using Cocoapods but the link provided doesn't have any information about an official pod.

I searched and found [official pods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google) by Google but there is no sign of the G+ SDK. Then I found [this](https://cocoapods.org/pods/google-plus-ios-sdk) pod and I'm not sure if it is safe to use or not as it is not maintained by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the version you provided in the first link, the name of the file itself contains **1.7.1**. The version on the CocoaPods site is marked as **1.7.1**. That's a *good* sign.

None of the people mentioned as maintainers of the pod are actually working in Google. That's a *bad* sign. At this point we don't know anything.

So after certain searching online, you'll find that the podspec, in fact, is in [this repository](https://github.com/adamotte/googleplus-ios-sdk). It is somebody else, who takes Google's code and puts it into his repo on GitHub.

**Answers for you:**

*Is it safe?* Probably yes, but it's not 100%. The code is visible in public repo, so the chances are really high that it is safe.

*Is it maintained by Google?* Nope.